# Shortest way to reverse Properties

Tags: java, properties

In Java I have a `java.util.Properties` object and I want to obtain another one with the same pairs but keys converted to values and viceversa.

If there are collision (i.e. there are two equal values) then just pick as value an arbitrary key.

What is the shortest way to do it?

Feel free to use libraries, commons-collections, or whatever.

Comment: You can use Java in Code Golf?  I thought it was just Perl, PHP, and Ruby. No?

Comment: I removed the code-golf tag, as it doesn't seem to me to be the typical code golf problem, but a real world problem that needs to be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Properties` object is a `Hashtable` object, so you should be able to do something like:

```
Hashtable<String, String> reversedProps = new Hashtable<String, String>();

for (String key : props.keySet()) {
    reversedProps.put(props.get(key), key);
}
```

Result: 3 lines of code.

This code is untested, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: `putAll` takes a `Map` as its argument, not two collections. For it to work, you need a "reversed" `Map`.

Comment: Also, it's Hashtable, not HashTable.

Comment: Removed the `putAll` solution - totally dropped the ball on that one. Also corrected the HashTable/Hashtable mistake.

Answer (score 6):

You can consider using a BiMap by google collections which is essentially a reversable Map. It guarantees uniquness of keys as well as values.

Check it out [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/). This is the [API](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)

Comment: This would indeed work, since Java's `Hashtable` class implements the `Map` interface, you can create a new BiMap and then use the `putAll()` method to load the `Properties` object into the BiMap.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
Properties fowards = new Properties();
fowards.load(new FileInputStream("local.properties"));

Properties backwards = new Properties();

for (String propertyName : fowards.stringPropertyNames())
{
  backwards.setProperty(forwards.get(propertyName), propertyName);
}
```

Comment: Can you use fowards.propertyNames() in the for-each loop like that? I've always created an object outside the for-each loop and done it that way. If you can, I can also remove a line of code from my example.

Comment: @Thomas: yes, the `for` loop gets the `Iterable` object before it starts iterating.

Comment: `propertyNames` returns an `Enumeration<?>`, not an `Iterable<String>`, and so cannot be iterated over with the foreach construct. `stringPropertyNames`, though, returns a `Set<String>` and can be foreached.